# How to Remove duplicate labels in subplot legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, subplot

The following code will generate a legend with duplicated labels. How to remove the duplicated one, so that there is only 1 label1 and 1 label2? One possible approach is to remove the duplicated item in the lines_labels list, but I couldn't figure out the code. Can someone please help? Thanks a lot!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
    
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224)
    
ax1.scatter(1,2,label='a',color='black')
ax1.plot(np.array([1, 2]), np.array([1, 2]),color='b',label='xvalues')
ax2.scatter(3,4,label='a',color='black')
ax3.scatter(5,6,label='b',color='red')
ax4.scatter(7,8,label='b',color='red')

    
lines_labels = [ax.get_legend_handles_labels() for ax in fig.axes]
lines, labels = [sum(lol, []) for lol in zip(*lines_labels)]
fig.legend(lines, labels, scatterpoints = 1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Try this: `lines_labels = [ax.get_legend_handles_labels() for i,ax in enumerate(fig.axes) if i == 0 or i == 2]`

Comment: Thanks, it works for this simplified code. But my actual code is more complicated, as it overlays many different curves, which need different labels, in each subplot. So your solution would disable the other labels in ax1 and ax3. Is there any way to identify the duplicated one by checking label name, rather than checking subplot name?

Comment: I have written the code only as an example, so if you specify only a large number of legend items it should be possible to accommodate. I too believe that there must be a better and best way.

Answer (score 1):

you could put all labels and lines in a dict and filter only for unique labels like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224)

ax1.scatter(1, 2, label='a', color='black')
ax1.plot(np.array([1, 2]), np.array([1, 2]), color='b', label='xvalues')
ax2.scatter(3, 4, label='a', color='black')
ax3.scatter(5, 6, label='b', color='red')
ax4.scatter(7, 8, label='b', color='red')

lines_labels = [ax.get_legend_handles_labels() for ax in fig.axes]
lines, labels = [sum(lol, []) for lol in zip(*lines_labels)]

# grab unique labels
unique_labels = set(labels)

# assign labels and legends in dict
legend_dict = dict(zip(labels, lines))

# query dict based on unique labels
unique_lines = [legend_dict[x] for x in unique_labels]

fig.legend(unique_lines, unique_labels, scatterpoints=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]